# Python - equivalent of Matlab/Octave keyboard function?

Tags: python

there is a function `keyboard` in Matlab/Octave that stops execution and gives control to the keyboard.

It would be useful thing to have around when I have a long running script and need to test a few things. Since Python is interpreted language I guess it should be possible.

Is there such a thing in Python or I should use something more 'Pythonic'? :)

Comment: You may be able to get something close to that with ipython notebook (project Jupyter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a debugger, such as pdb or ipdb.  Once you've acquired the module, just add the following line to your code where you want to stop it:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

You can use [these commands](http://web.archive.org/web/20190329091222/http://georgejhunt.com/olpc/pydebug/pydebug/ipdb.html) to move through the code once you have control.

Comment: Type `q` to quit the debugger.

Answer (score 9):

Since Python 3.7 you can use built-in `breakpoint()` function, as described in [PEP 553](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/). In previous Python versions you would use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` as the accepted answer states.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using an IDE, use the [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). If you are using an IDE, use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: Python debugger is not the same. You don't have a python console. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: By IDE I mean an [integrated development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). MATLAB requires you to use one, which it calls the "console". Python doesn't require its use.

Comment: you can also run MATLAB without an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Returns IDE command prompt just like `keyboard` in MATLAB, whereas pdb seems to be more focused on stepping through breakpoints in the code (although I haven't used pdb much so haven't dived into much of the functionality)

From: http://ubuntugeeknerd.blogspot.com/2013/12/matlab-keyboard-equivalent-in-python.html

Further documentation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-python-with-an-interactive-console